# Breaking reference to object in Python

Tags: python, reference

If I write the following code:

```
a = []
b = a
b.append(2)
```

Then a = [2]. Is there a way I can break the reference between b and a, so that even if I modify b, a will not be modified?

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you copy its content with

```
b=a[:]
```